# What are the defaults regex used by filter_var?

Tags: php, regex, default, filter-var

Are the regex used by the PHP function **filter_var** mentioned somewhere ?

Comment: Check the source code https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/250938e2d35fc54161a18167b7901c5e3b574371/ext/filter/sanitizing_filters.c

Comment: Is it the official source ? So they are not using regex ?

Answer (score 0):

The source code may be a little difficult to traverse, even if you know what you're looking for. I've linked the files which define how `filter_var` works below.

Near the top of https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/filter.c you should be able to see the `filter_list` array which matches the PHP filter constants with their corresponding filtering functions. `filter_var` is defined within this file, but we can ignore it for now.

The filters themselves are all defined in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c.

You may notice that not all of the filters use regex. Indeed, from a quick glance the only one I saw using any regex patterns was `php_filter_validate_email`. The others seem to have alternative logic necessary for them to function efficiently, and don't require regular expressions to filter their content.

My explanations above have been simplified to answer the question. I suggest that you use `filter_var` with the appropriate flags where possible, rather than attempting to reverse engineer or re-invent the wheel, as there is additional logic involved and it makes your code that much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

yes they are mainly of 4 types :

```
Validate filters
Sanitize filters
Other filters
Filter flags
```

more information :

> http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Comment: I wasn't looking for the types of filters but the regex used to apply those filters.